# how decrypt telegram web request

Tags: encryption, aes, telegram, sha256, mtproto

i want create app that controll telegram such as auto post and add contact automatic and answer message auto and etc but
when i inspect element and see request it's encypted
here is response

```
p)„ÇfHãýØ¬Ê®3Õˆoè÷ùv¶r|VÜj.øeà^8Ì™Bígªx¯rMì¦Šâ¿Šëm¾÷Ùed„+7dnõ¨‰ÜAQ@¨ôÁ¨ôãi;ðhhúcÏ&©S    ŠeÅE"ŒœÍ™2·Hq(¢¦ÎšKI"áÃ¦àîÍ#³k_Ã?˜¨ë\în€1…EîñÝc8à?%üx×9“_—Û3ñ„JîÄX³ØþŸš™0!‡„    _ëìÂ÷½DÑYR±ÝûñÖ}³nš_0ŠñPÖø@‘•x"Z>Ÿ?Òì`AîxÔ9ù:JÇfp0÷*m€‚C8b»c‡GÎïX1±Ä/íD]:~?‰HûÃ^›¶Ÿ†œÉ(í;íÿÿz*sÐP+)ÁyS©1Åï&ƒÆò… ~>QWù_"`j‘¡/yN¯¶ˆŠá°á}–¤ZËøÏl2ýù¯•6ÑžÙŸSQ
X\3jU¨`·Qe¯-®U²yÕF`Ÿ9|cUýè’èõÿZæ¯ÝO!‚èÚzCwÉ}KŸmëè&›exMÖÙ®y‚%™~Ä^›Ía+5õ  ÈˆûNA¯5Êz`*±y«•qjË6­¸ÅŠ×?mOnÛa%¸¾n„ÑàœkœR‹ü1¤U‚®¾U˜ZÀçñï'rŽWšdÃìQ£êVN(é”fy†”!¶¼pk'è«¦ÚòøôÂöSopRŒv¯bóP¼ûé Áp/Pµd·ƒ#û³ˆÉÁý•|§1Å™%
L…–aÚøškk—VjÜÏAõÝH^r']8–œá˜ÝªpÇòu=7F¬Iù+%{|
```

[image: here http header from server]

[image: it's request that encrypted]

it's encrypted in client side how can i decrypt it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is encrypted for security reasons.

For functionality, you requested it is better to use an [official Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api).

To access API you can use libraries like [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) that allows to simulate user behavior. See their [documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/) for more details.